# Bogus data in output CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to change delimiter on CSV and write to a new file, is just a simple modification but isn't it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- econde: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import csv

def main():


    r = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
    wr = open(sys.argv[2],"a+")

    rea = csv.reader(r, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(wr,delimiter="|", quotechar="'")
    for row in rea:
        #line = str(row).replace(",","|")
        #writer.writerow("".join(line))
        writer.writerow(row)

    print type(row)
    print row
    r.close()
    wr.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Update:**

The output in console looks so so like:

```
./csv_read.py fim.csv salida.csv
<type 'list'>
['9/17/18 22:29', 'any', 'la_cuerda.net', 'Sep 17 22:29:29 running yum[37144]: Installed: ImageMagic-toolkit-2.1.7-1.noarch']
```

but in the file is writing 3 times the same string but on three different ways

the first way is still the same: 1 char per field (wrong format and brackets are included)

the second way is inserting all in one cell without split it like the original

This is the content of the Input File and the Output file

```
$ cat Input.csv
Time(GMT),Host,dest,Alert
9/17/18 22:34,any,google.com.mx,monitor: Agent started: 'discovery.channel.org->any'.
9/17/18 22:29,any,la_cuerda.net,Sep 17 22:29:29 running yum[37144]: Installed: ImageMagic-toolkit-2.1.7-1.noarch

$ cat Output.csv
[,'''',T,i,m,e,(,G,M,T,),'''',|, ,'''',H,o,s,t,'''',|, ,'''',d,e,s,t,'''',|, ,'-''',A,l,e,r,t,'''',]
[,'''',9,/,1,7,/,1,8, ,2,2,:,3,4,'''',|, ,'''',a,n,y,'''',|, ,'''',g,o,o,g,l,e,.,c,o,m,.,m,x,'''',|, ,",m,o,n,i,t,o,r,:, ,A,g,e,n,t, ,s,t,a,r,t,e,d,:, ,'''',d,i,s,c,o,v,e,r,y,.,c,h,a,n,n,e,l,.,o,r,g,-,>,a,n,y,'''',.,",]
[,'''',9,/,1,7,/,1,8, ,2,2,:,2,9,'''',|, ,'''',a,n,y,'''',|, ,'''',l,a,_,c,u,e,r,d,a,.,n,e,t,'''',|, ,'''',S,e,p, ,1,7, ,2,2,:,2,9,:,2,9, ,r,u,n,n,i,n,g, ,y,u,m,[,3,7,1,4,4,],:, ,I,n,s,t,a,l,l,e,d,:, ,I,m,a,g,e,M,a,g,i,c,-,t,o,o,l,k,i,t,-,2,.,1,.,7,-,1,.,n,o,a,r,c,h,'''',]
Time(GMT)|Host|dest|Alert
9/17/18 22:34|any|google.com.mx|'monitor: Agent started: ''discovery.channel.org->any''.'
9/17/18 22:29|any|la_cuerda.net|Sep 17 22:29:29 running yum[37144]: Installed: ImageMagic-toolkit-2.1.7-1.noarch
Time(GMT)|Host|dest|Alert
9/17/18 22:34|any|google.com.mx|'monitor: Agent started: ''discovery.channel.org->any''.'
9/17/18 22:29|any|la_cuerda.net|Sep 17 22:29:29 running yum[37144]: Installed: ImageMagic-toolkit-2.1.7-1.noarch
Time(GMT)|Host|dest|Alert
9/17/18 22:34|any|google.com.mx|'monitor: Agent started: ''discovery.channel.org->any''.'
9/17/18 22:29|any|la_cuerda.net|Sep 17 22:29:29 running yum[37144]: Installed: ImageMagic-toolkit-2.1.7-1.noarch
```

Comment: interesting question, to begin with the program is doing what you have coded it to do, which might not always be aligned with what you want or expect it to do. Let's begin breaking this down. what do you see when you print `row` in the loop?

Comment: If you read the documentation for csv you will see that you can specify the deliimter for writer by doing no more that `writer = csv.writer(wr,delimiter=‘*’,quotechar=“‘“)` so there is absolutely no need for modifying `line` or for `””.join(line)`. Also read the documentation. And look at the examples. Then code up the examples and see they work. Then extend them incrementally towards what you want to do.

Comment: @ahed87 thanks for your answer but the output looks well in console 

['9/17/18 22:29'| 'any'| 'la_cuerda.net'| 'Sep 17 22:29:29 running yum[37144]: Installed: ImageMagic-toolkit-2.1.7-1.noarch']

but still insterting the brackets and quotes and each char as individual per field

Comment: @barny Thanks for your answer, I will try as you mention 

ok I run it but now is writting 9 lines and the original has 3, I don't know how to upload a picture to show you the output on the file because in console looks well 

<type 'list'>
['9/17/18 22:29', 'any', 'la_cuerda.net', 'Sep 17 22:29:29 running yum[37144]: Installed: ImageMagic-toolkit-2.1.7-1.noarch']

 rea = csv.reader(r, delimiter=',')
 writer = csv.writer(wr,delimiter="|", quotechar="'")
 for row in rea:
  writer.writerow(row)

 print type(row)
 print row

Comment: Edit your question showing your current code and its output, and some lines of the input file.

Comment: @barny is done, so I don't know why is writing all in a wrong way, you can try the code if you want

Comment: You still need to show what the input file looks like - the first few lines. And why are you opening the output "a+" because that's a bit strange - just for testing, change it to "wb" until it works? Input maybe should also be opened "rb" - read the CSV documentation  says "If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference." and there's nothing to be lost by opening with explicit b

Comment: Your code only prints the last row - what happens differently if you indent the print statements so they are in the for loop - i.e. so each row is printed?

Comment: I added the input and output files on the body of the post @barny

Comment: The output you've given is not what the program produces for me. So, no [mcve].

Comment: @barny Hi, I checked again with the wb so as you and ivan_pozdeev said, the putput is different it was showing another output because the a+ so the output in console looks well but in the file is writing in 1 cell and not on each

I also edited the button of the post to show the last output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wr = open(sys.argv[2],"a+")` is the cause. Each time you run your program, it *appends* its output to the file. The bogus data you see is from previous runs.

Unless your program is really supposed to append to the output file rather than overwrite it, `open` the file in `wb` mode.

Also note that [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) docs mandate opening the file in binary mode (because the module is supposed to do its own transcoding).

Comment: that's true but still writing all in one cell and not in each but yes the output was changed